# Parsing JSON arrays with quoted content

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I used JSON.stringify on a variable, let's call it x. I get the following result

```
[["<blockquote ..."]]
```

I tried to get x[0], but I get this when I get JSON.stringify

```
[
```

x[0][0] gets me the same thing.

Why is this and how can I just get the quotes in between the two array brackets?
Is this also a proper JSON array?

Comment: `Is this also a proper JSON array?` yes check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Wait. JSON stringify returns a **string**. You try to access the 0-th element of a string, which is **char**. And you get it.

Comment: You are completely right.

Comment: I called x[0][0] and x[0] without the stringify

Comment: No, I am asking what the best way to get inside the quote. I suppose right now I could get away with substring from 2 to length - 3 ? Is there a better way?